# 400 error when upsert using Cosmos SP

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to execute the below SP

```
function createMyDocument() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var doc = {
        "someId": "123134444",
    };
    var options = {};
    options['PartitionKey'] =  ["someId"];

    var isAccepted = collection.upsertDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), doc, options, function (error, resources, options) {

    });

}
```

and cosmos keeps on complaining that there's something wrong with the partition key

```
    { code: 400,
      body: '{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\\"Errors\\":
[\\"PartitionKey extracted from document doesn\'t match the one specified in the header\\"]}
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how to pass in the partion key in `options` so it gets pass this validation ?

Comment: Hi ,any updates? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: no, i'll post the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The error was with how we call the stored proc.

How we were doing it

```
 client.executeStoredProcedure('dbs/db1/colls/coll-1/sprocs/createMyDocument',
        {},
        {} //Here you have to pass in the partition key
```

);

How it has to be

```
     client.executeStoredProcedure('dbs/db1/colls/coll-1/sprocs/createMyDocument',
            {},
            {"partitionKey": "43321"} 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the meaning of `partitionkey` property in the `options[]`.

For example , my container is created like this:

[image]

The partition key is "name" for my collection here. You could check your collection's partition key.

And my documents as below :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "jay"
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "jay2"
}
```

My `partitionkey` is **'name'**, so here I have two paritions : **'jay'** and **'jay1'**.

So, here you should set the `partitionkey` property to **'123134444'** in your question, not **'someId'**.

More details about [cosmos db partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data).

Hope it helps you.